# Autenticação de usuário em java utilizando banco Mysql e Framework spring boot

Tags: java

**boa tarde.
estou em desenvolvimento de uma aplicacao web utilizando o framework spring boot,hibernate e jpa com o banco de dados mysql. enfim estou com uma duvida sobre a autenticação deste usuário pois ate o momento consigo apenas salvar este usuário no banco de dados porem como consigo autentica-lo e saber se os dados no banco e o mesmo que o usuario esta digitando no form? bom.. vou mostrar aqui a parte apenas do backend pois a duvida esta toda no backend.
esta e a parte onde utilizei o hibernate.**

```
/**
 Classe de persistência de dados ao banco mysql
 */
```

package com.web.Models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "login")
public class Login implements Serializable{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -7123394242940032066L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "usuario")
private String usuario;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "senha")
private String senha;


public Login() {

}
public Login(String usuario, String senha, long id) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.senha = senha;
    this.id = id;
}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}
public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}
public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}
```

}

**aqui o repository**

```
package com.web.Repository;
```

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.web.Models.Login;

@Repository
public interface LoginRepository extends CrudRepository{

}

**e aqui o controller os mapeamentos cadastrar usuario funcionam normalmente apenas o validarUsuario que nao funciona ainda.**

```
package com.web.Controller;
```

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.web.Models.Login;
import com.web.Repository.LoginRepository;
import com.web.Util.Log;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private LoginRepository repository;

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cadastrarUsuario", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String form() {
    return "addUser/cadastrarLogin";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/cadastrarUsuario", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String form(Login login) {
    repository.save(login);
    return "redirect:/cadastrarUsuario";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/validarUsuario", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String validform() {
    return "validUsuario/validarLogin";
}
```

**pois apenas a parte do controller que nao consigo validar este usuario, nao criei uma classe service por motivos de exercicio da faculdade apenas com repository,controller e model, alquem pode me ajudar?**

```
}
```

Comment: WeltonSistemas, vc já pensou em utilizar JWT ou outro mecanismo de autenticação e autorização? Estou te enviando um link para dar uma olhada. https://receitasdecodigo.com.br/spring-boot/autenticacao-com-jwt-em-projetos-spring-boot

Comment: Caso na verdade busque fazer somente uma simulação sem usar nenhum mecanismo de autenticação, ou seja, caso queira fazer só uma consulta validando se o usuário existe ou não poste ai.